# updating variable value javascript

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I'm making a calender, where the user can click on an image to go to the previous year. 
I have a global variable called currentYear, it is being used in the whole program.

My question is:
how can I change (update) its value once the user click that image? With my code, it does change but it doesn't update in the other statments.

```
    <button onClick="dec()">test</button>
    <script> 
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    function dec() { 
    currentYear--; 
    }​
    document.write(currentYear); // outside the function 
    </script>
```

Comment: You are new with javascript? Read some modern books about JavaScript. Your code is 2000-ish with inline events, global variables, etc.

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't update in the other statements'? A variable is just a container for a value. It's not that changing it affects all code that previously used it. If I write something down, let you read it, you will know what is on the paper. But if I then change it, you don't know what is on the paper and maybe you don't even know that I changed it. With variables it's the same.

Comment: Your codes looks fine to me. Do you have a test page?

Comment: Sounds to me that you have some UI that depends on currentYear, and expect that UI to change when you change currentYear. Correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway.. that don't work, you will have to write code that updates the UI. Maybe based on an event you trigger. You could also benefit from using a framework like knockoutjs that does this for you.

Comment: @GolezTrol : you got my point and you explained it perfectly , is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

[seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZwNR/):

```
<button onClick="dec()">test</button>
<script>

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

    function dec() {
        currentYear--;
        alert(currentYear);
    }​

</script>
```

Comment: ok it works fine in that case , but what if I wanted to do this : 

       <button onClick="dec()">test</button>
<script>

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

    function dec() {
        currentYear--;
        alert(currentYear);
    }​


document.write(currentYear); // outside the function
</script>


first it will write the previous value of current year ,  I want it to be updated once the user click that button , how is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to keep in mind when defining and using global variables:

1. The variable should be declared in the global scope.  This means that the `var currentDate;` declaration must not be in any sort of function.  If it's declared in the global scope, it's value will last for the duration of the web page and so you can access it from anywhere at any time during the life of that web page view.  There are a couple other ways to declare it that cause it to go into the global scope, but this is the simplest.
2. There must be no other variables with the same name that have been declared in the scope in which you want to use the global variable.  This means no local variables of that name and no function arguments of that name as a conflicting variable of the same name will take precedence and override access to that name.
3. If all else fails, you can force a variable into the global scope by accessing it with the `window.` prefix like this `window.currentYear = 2011;` but you shouldn't have to do it this way.

If none of these seem to apply to your particular situation, then you're not showing us enough of your code for us to see what's really going on because your general code should work if it's at the global scope.

Comment: yes I think I didn't show enough of my code , look at this code it may show you what im looking for : 
<button onClick="dec()">test</button> <script> var currentDate = new Date(); var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear(); function dec() { currentYear--; alert(currentYear); }​ document.write(currentYear); // outside the function </script>

-first the document.write(value) will print out the previous year 
I want it to update the value and print it again once the user click that button ...
is that possible ?

Comment: @Laila92 - multiline code isn't readable in comments.  Please edit this code into your question where it can be made readable and then refer to it from a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way , if you're interested this is how I did it :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="llo"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
    var val = 2012;
    var id;
    var counter = 0 ;
    function decrementYear(){
    id="laila"+counter;
    counter=counter+1;
    val=val+1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility='hidden';
    str="<table id='laila"+(counter)+"' border='1'><tr><td>"+(val)+"</td><td onclick='decrementYear()'>clickHere</td></tr></table>";
    document.getElementById("llo").innerHTML = str;
    }
    str="<table id='laila"+(counter)+"' border='1'><tr><td>"+(val)+"</td><td   onclick='decrementYear()'>clickHere</td></tr></table>";
    document.getElementById("llo").innerHTML = str;
    </script>
    </html>
```